# Invoked from a directive, angular growl not show

Tags: angularjs, directive, growl

I was using angular growl, which is quite good for showing message.
(https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl)

It OK to add a message in a controller, but when add a message in a directive, it's not show, why?
Here is my test code.

a.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="https://raw.github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl/master/src/growl.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular-growl/angular-growl.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular-route/angular-route.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view=""></div>
<div growl="" class='growl-container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

a.js

```
'use strict';

var module = angular.module('a', ['ngRoute', 'angular-growl']);
module.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'IndexCtrl',
    template: '<button aaa>aaaa</button>'
});
}]);

module.controller('IndexCtrl', ['growl', function (growl) {
growl.addErrorMessage('haha');
}]);

module.directive('aaa', ['growl', function (growl) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function (e) {
            console.log('aaa');
            growl.addErrorMessage('aaa');
            growl.addErrorMessage('bbb');
        });
    }
};
}]);

var $html = angular.element(document);
$html.ready(function () {
angular.bootstrap($html, ['a']);
$html.addClass('ng-app');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have events outside of angular that change angular scopes you need to use `$apply` to inform angular that changes are made and to run a digest cycle.

If you were to use `ng-click` instead you wouldn't run into this problem.

To resolve with current external event code:

```
element.bind('click', function (e) {
       scope.$apply(function(){
            growl.addErrorMessage('aaa');           
      })
});
```

Comment: Appreciated, that's exactly the root cause.
But why angular doesn't automatically do that in element.bind, you think it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Good to see your problem solved! But no, angular can't do that automatically in a callback function that you define yourself and which is called by the browser. Exactly for this, $apply was created. But the much better solution here would be to use the already mentioned ng-click. Good luck with angular-growl!

Comment: The reason I wrote a 'aaa' directive instead of ng-click='aaa()' is that, one of my partner provide html&css to me, he think it's good to use semantic HTML, by write 'do-login' directive, I can bind login event to a button, he think add a 'do-login' or 'data-do-login' is more acceptable, ng-click="doLogin()" seems too programmatic(although both of them are directives).

Comment: If you want to use angularJS, you *should* use angularJS. Really.

Comment: angular directives like `ng-click` already call `$apply` internally.